# Running docker container from debian:stretch image does not work

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a container based on the debian:stretch image, but this does not work:

```
docker container run --detach debian:stretch
```

outputs:

```
7976eb7074289a741a2b183634345fc8519359cba4d543c03b0a6d4e5d7e0d53
```

And

```
docker ps -a
```

outputs:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7976eb707428        debian:stretch      "bash"              3 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       vigorous_lumiere
```

Whereas it works well with the latest nginx image:

```
docker run --detach nginx:latest
```

53ed18b5d1a7c72aa92bab0ca679269514db79f31a1d3759c2e25c7fdb1e82ff

```
docker ps -a
```

outputs:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
53ed18b5d1a7        nginx:latest        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 seconds ago        Up 2 seconds                    80/tcp              admiring_hawking
7976eb707428        debian:stretch      "bash"                   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       vigorous_lumiere
```

Why does the container based on the debian:stretch image that I am instantiating does not work?
Does this come from the debian image?

I am running Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container literally doesn’t do anything: it starts a shell, but since it’s running as a background process and doesn’t have anything on its stdin, it immediately exits.

You should read the official Docker tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  Generally you should work by building your application into a custom image, setting up that image’s default CMD to run your application, and using `docker build` and `docker run` (or a tool like Docker Compose) to run the assembly.  There’s not much point in running a plain Linux distribution container.

(Also remember that it’s extremely routine to `docker rm` containers, and so anything you do in an interactive shell in a container is very likely to get lost.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. [This resource](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21) give a good understanding of the CMD and ENTRYPOINT directives